# Call javascript function after html.action is returned in mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a method named `myAction` in `myController`.
`myAction` is called via ajax multiple times.
It returns a view and everytime when it is returned I set some properties in $(document).ready();

But to be specific, I want to call a javascript function when it is called from `@html.action()`
For the first time I am calling this method using

```
@html.action("myAction", "myController", new with {.attr= "thisAttr"})
```

in view.

I want to call a javascript funtion when view is returned from `@html.action().`

Is there any other way to call an action in controller to render a dynamic view.?
or any other solution besides using ViewBag in javascript?

Comment: Can you just put javascript call in the view return from myaction and it would just run ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but maybe there's an @Ajax.Action function that allows this? Is it supposed to run a Javascript or C# function?

Comment: I have already checked it but there is not function like that under @Ajax

Comment: Okay, but again, are you trying to run a Javascript function or a C# function?

Comment: I need to call a javascript function after the call is returned from @html.Action.
May be there wud be another way around